# Magento Compilation Scopes Count 43

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have noticed that my Magento CE 1.9.0.1 compilation configuration look very strange.

- Collected Files Count 11083
- Compiled Scopes Count 43

Normally is around 4

Looks like a lot of core parts of Magento are included in the count where in the default Magento is not.
Anybody knows how check if all is correct?
Regards